# AWS amplify Angular custom authenticator component

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am following the guide on this page: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular to build a sign-in page for my website.

After several hours of setting up, I got a result like this:

[image]

Now I need to remove the `Create account` button, how can I do that?

I've tried to search a lot on the internet but all of the tutorials are for React not Angular.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 8 and lower, hide it with css:

```
.amplify-form-signup {
  display: none;
}
```

For Angular 9 and up, add `hide-sign-up` to your sign-in slot:

```
<amplify-authenticator>
  <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" hide-sign-up></amplify-sign-in>
  <app-myapp></app-myapp>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case you haven't figured it out yet:

you can override the angular component. So in your case you'd probably want to create your own

component
and create one that does not have a Create Account link

I think this is the most detailed part I could find on the amplify page:
Check [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular#using-authentication-components-without-the-authenticator)